# Get microsoft account name for current user in powershell

Tags: powershell

How can I get the Microsoft account username for the current user in PowerShell? I see how to get the local username (e.g. $env:username and others like it), but not the Microsoft account name (which is typically an email address).
Thank you for any help!
Ari

Comment: `"$env:USERNAME@$env:USERDNSDOMAIN"` _may_ give you the user's email address, depending on your DNS setup.

Comment: What is a Microsoft acccount name? And more important: Where is it stored. Is it the email addresse or not? The user principal name maybe? What ever the solution is, it doesn't help you if it's working *typically* right ;)

Comment: Theo, unfortunately I wasn't able to use any of them to resolve the email address for users logging in using a Microsoft account outside of the o365 or AD environment. All I was able to get was user name from local machine.

Answer (score 1):

If by `Microsoft account username` you mean the login name used for Office 365, then depending on how you have set up the O365 accounts, you will probably want the `EmailAddress` or `UserPrincipalName` property.

Using the PowerShell `ActiveDirectory` module you could do this like so:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$currentUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $env:USERNAME -Properties EmailAddress, UserPrincipalName
$msAccountName = $currentUser.EmailAddress
# or $msAccountName = $currentUser.UserPrincipalName
```

You can also do this the 'LDAP'-way, without the need of importing the ActiveDirectory module:

```
$msAccountName = ([ADSI]"LDAP://<SID=$([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().User.Value)>").UserPrincipalName
```

or something like:

```
$msAccountName = ([adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$env:USERNAME)").FindOne().Properties.mail
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking to find this info for your personal laptop (out of domain, o365 or AD) then try these registry keys.:

`get-childitem hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\UserExtendedProperties\ | sele
ct pschildname`

`Get-ChildItem Registry::HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\Stored
Identities\ | select pschildname`

`Get-ChildItem Registry::HKEY_USERS\*\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\UserExtendedP
roperties\* | select pschildname`

I believe Microsoft captures a string of your email to create a user account so you can do something like this to figure currently logged in user's email:

`get-childitem hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\UserExtendedProperties\ | where{$_.pschildname -like "*$env:USERNAME*"} | select pschildname`

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're indeed looking for the **UserPrincipalName** of the logged in user, `whoami /upn` will give you this information.

I don't know of any more powershellish way to get it.

`whoami` uses cached information from the current session, and it seems to be the only way to get the current user's UPN without requesting Active Directory servers.